# tailwindcss is not loading when in a subfolder within src

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, vite

I started a fresh vue.js project with `npm init vue@latest` and by default this creates an `assets` folder within the `src` folder where it stores the `logo.svg` and two .css files (`base.css` and `main.css`).

Now I wanted to add Tailwind CSS and followed the [instructions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite#vue) provided by the tailwind crew. They say the tailwind directives have to be in a file located in the src folder:

> Add the @tailwind directives for each of Tailwind’s layers to your ./src/style.css file.

When i place them there everything works fine, but when i use the `@import './tailwind.css';` in my `src/assets/main.css` file it wont import it from there, only when i move the main.css file one level up directly into src itself.

I can't figure out why it won't import tailwind properly or where I have to make a change to set a different path to tailwind css. Am I the only one with this proplem or does someone have a solution other then "move css into src folder"?

Comment: Faced same problem in angular. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The [instructions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite#vue) are for the Vite CLI. With `npm init vue@latest` you are getting the results of the Vue CLI which creates the `main.css` and `base.css` you are seeing. In that case you can add the imports of the Tailwind layers to the `main.css` below the `@import './base.css/` and subsequently import the `main.css` stylesheet in your application.